# JAVAFX - Split Menu Button close

Tags: java, javafx, fxml

When I select an item from the menu, the menu selection closes. Here's my fxml code:

```
<SplitMenuButton id="menu" layoutX="35.0" layoutY="175.0" mnemonicParsing="false" text="Privacidade ">
        <items>
            <CheckMenuItem text="IP" />
            <CheckMenuItem mnemonicParsing="false" text="Nome do usuário" />
            <CheckMenuItem mnemonicParsing="false" text="Nome do Computador " />
        </items>
</SplitMenuButton>
```

All that I want to do is let the user select multiple items without closing the menu.

Comment: I would say to call the menu.show() method in order to display the context menu. But it's seems to me that it does nothing if you call it inside the CheckMenuItem's setOnAction. It's like when the checkMenuItem action event ends it forces to close the context menu, and consuming the event doesn't work either, but i might missing something.

Comment: I guess one way would be to use a `CustomMenuItem` and place your own check box inside it; `CustomMenuItem` has a `hideOnClick` property you can set to `false`. But that seems like quite a lot of extra work for something that it seems should be easy.